# How can I approximate this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
1/(Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] (17.9 + 1. wn)) E^(-5. t) (29972.7 Sqrt[ 2. - 4. wn] (-24.1 + 1. wn) + 
  E^(t (4.3 + 0.5 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn])) (-4730.44 - 3262.47 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 
    wn (893475. + 25741.4 Sqrt[ 2. - 4. wn] + (22915.3 + 3409.85 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] - 
      577.94 wn) wn)) + E^(t (4.3 - 0.5 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn])) (4730.44 - 
        3262.47 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + wn (-893475. + 25741.4 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 
          wn (-22915.3 + 3409.85 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 577.94 wn))))
```

It is known that the range of `wn` is $[6.28,13]$.

How can I simplify my expression?

Comment: It is not really clear (at least to me) what is being asked here.

Comment: Known range of wn is 6.28~13, how to simplify the equation

Comment: `Series`?  `PadeApproximant`?

Comment: Thank you, what can you say in detail? I am a newbie

Comment: Try Help > Wolfram Documentation

Comment: "Approximate" and "simplify" mean different things.  Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[expr, expr2]

expr[wn_, t_] = 
  1/(Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] (17.9 + 1. wn)) E^(-5. t) (29972.7 Sqrt[
       2. - 4. wn] (-24.1 + 1. wn) + 
     E^(t (4.3 + 0.5 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn])) (-4730.44 - 3262.47 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] +
         wn (893475. + 
           25741.4 Sqrt[
             2. - 4. wn] + (22915.3 + 3409.85 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] - 
              577.94 wn) wn)) + 
     E^(t (4.3 - 0.5 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn])) (4730.44 - 3262.47 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 
        wn (-893475. + 25741.4 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 
           wn (-22915.3 + 3409.85 Sqrt[2. - 4. wn] + 577.94 wn))));
```

Assuming also that `t` is positive

```
expr2[wn_, t_] = 
 Assuming[{6.28 < wn < 13, t > 0}, 
  expr[wn, t] // Rationalize // 
    ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // FullSimplify]

(* (E^(-5 t) (299727 Sqrt[-2 + 4 wn] (-241 + 10 wn) + 
     2 E^(43 t/
       10) (Sqrt[-2 + 4 wn] (-326247 + 5 wn (514828 + 68197 wn)) Cos[
          1/2 t Sqrt[-2 + 4 wn]] + 
        2 (-236522 + wn (44673750 + (1145765 - 28897 wn) wn)) Sin[
          1/2 t Sqrt[-2 + 4 wn]])))/(10 Sqrt[-2 + 4 wn] (179 + 10 wn)) *)

Plot3D[expr2[wn, t], {wn, 6.28, 13}, {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, AxesLabel -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 12}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to simplify your expression so that you might better understand it then notice the many examples of `2.-4. wn` in your expression.

Changing all `wn` to `x+1/2` and then changing all `x` to `y^2` makes your expression simpler.

I believe the result is then

```
1/(E^(5.*t)*(18.4*y + y^3))*(-707355.72*y + y^3 +
E^(t*(4.3 + 0.5*y))*( 447663.6425 + 10460.6925*y + 22482.845*y^2 + 3410.85*y^3 + 22048.39*y^4 + 3409.85*y^5 - 577.94*y^6) + 
E^(t*(4.3 - 0.5*y))*(-447663.6425 + 10460.6925*y - 22482.845*y^2 + 3410.85*y^3 - 22048.39*y^4 + 3409.85*y^5 + 577.94*y^6))
```

Because of the symmetry in that it might be possible for you to even further simplify this.

Please check all this very carefully to make certain that no mistake has been made.

Watch carefully for the complex numbers involved in your expression.